# Qgis on Ubuntu - change permitions?

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, server

First time using (QGIS on UBUNTU).
i am following some articles in order to publish qgis maps on the web.
My problem is (although i am the administrator) i am not able to save or copy my *.qgs in specific directories like /qgis-web-client/project.
I don' t even know where are some directories, since i am really confused with the ubuntu file structure philosophy.
Is there any way to change permissions? Is that a good idea?

Comment: are you using the sudo command? http://linux.wikia.com/wiki/Sudo to copy?

Comment: Sudo is a tool used for administrative purposes. I would not use it to move around your working data. Your user has a home folder `/home/[youruser]` where your data should be stored normally. Unless you have a good reason to store it to another place, I would stick to this. I normally have a folder `/home/user/Documents/GeoData` where I save all my projects and layers, but it's up to you to find a good solution for this.

Comment: This is the point. My data are at home/user/documents/gis/projects/oropos/oropos.qgs, and i must put a copy or save the project in a specific directory. But i can save only in /home/user/..... Yes i use sudo command, but it' s nice to save your files using the software interface.